# Uploading data with file with Guzzle - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading a file to my API built on laravel. In my code below, the data is sent to the API. But how can i get the file that was uploaded to the API ?

**Controller**

```
$file = $request->file('imported-file');
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path ='/Users/desktop/Folder/laravelapp/public/Voice/';
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $fileinfo = array(
            'message'          =>  'Testing content',
            'recipient'  =>  "102425",
        );

        $res = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'FileContents',
                    'contents' => file_get_contents($path . $name),
                    'filename' => $name
                ],
                [
                    'name'     => 'FileInfo',
                    'contents' => json_encode($fileinfo)
                ]
            ],
        ]);
```

**API Controller**

```
        if (!empty('FileInfo')) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'file_content' => $request->file('FileContents'),
                'media'=>$request->hasFile('FileContents'),
            ]);
        }
```

This is the response, i get `"file":null,"file_content":{},"media":true`

Why is the file content empty when `media` is showing true meaning there is  a file ?

Comment: How are you sending the file to your controller?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons :

- Check your content type. Sometimes we forget to specify multipart/form-data and the request is sent with generic application/x-form-urlencoded etc.
- Secondly if you are using jQuery, then set :

contentType: false,
processData: false,
cache: false

This will help your form request no getting converted to string payload and not forcing ajax to set content type. try  using FormData.

Update : Found similar answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) has detailed answer for this.